# is there any alternate API for NetRemoteTOD(server,Struct),to retrieve the time from server machine

Tags: c#, c++, objective-c, loops, cppunit

I use NetRemoteTOD(Server, (LPBYTE *)&TimeOfDay) to retrieve the time information from a server. Is there any other alternate to get those details other than the above?

Comment: For which platform you need? You didnt tag any.

Comment: For windows platform..And using cpp

Comment: Then why do you need "alternate" ?